# How do you not display the prompt box when creating text file in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a `.bat` file that runs through an activity, but everytime the `.bat` file creates the text document, it displays the prompt "Are you sure you want to create the `.txt` file? How do I remove this box and go straight to creating it?

Example.bat:

```
@echo off
cd Documents
if not EXIST new.txt (
start notepad.exe new.txt <---How do I modify this so that it doesn't display the pop-up?
goto fail
) else (
echo The activity is ready!
)
:go
echo Would you like to start the activity?
set /p var="(Y/N): "
if /i %var%==y  ( 
goto start
) else (
goto EOF
)
:start
echo Beginning...
del /p new.txt
pause
goto EOF
:fail
echo Now the activity is ready!
goto go
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the file before opening it in notepad.

Something like:

```
echo "" > new.txt
start notepad.exe new.txt
```